# Use a batch file to execute a VBA macro on all word docs in a folder

Tags: vba, batch-file

I have several .docm files in a folder. Each file has a VBA macro called SaveFormData which saves the file's legacy field forms into a .txt file and then closes the .docm. I'm trying to create a batch file that will execute the macros within each file, without having to directly call each file. Here's what I've got so far...

```
@echo off
set myPath=C:\Users\Long File Path with Spaces\

for /f %%f in (%myPath%) do echo ("C:\Some other path\WINWORD.EXE" /mSaveFormData)
```

I don't really have any experience creating batch files so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I've tried following what some of the other posts have done regarding using a batch file to act on multiple files in a folder, but I've had no success other than through calling each file individually like so, but I know that's not very efficient.

```
@echo off
set myPath=C:\Users\Long File Path with Spaces\

"C:\Some other path\WINWORD.EXE" /mSaveFormData "%myPath%DocName1.docm"
"C:\Some other path\WINWORD.EXE" /mSaveFormData "%myPath%DocName2.docm"
```

Comment: `for /f` is for reading a file and going through the contents of it line by line. To loop over files in a directory, you need to get rid of the /f flag and maybe give a wildcard for filename matching, e.g. `for %%f in (%mypath%\*.docm)` or similar. (I'm not posting this as an answer yet, because I'm not sure that's enough to make it work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over all the files in a directory, read `help for` and then try this `for` command in the command line.

```
for %a in (*.docm) do @echo %~fa
```

to iterate recursively to all the directories and subdirectories

```
for /r %a in (*.docm) do @echo %~fa
```

Finally, replace `echo` with the appropiate command, and arrange a bit the syntax for a bat file

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Users\Long File Path with Spaces"
set "winword=C:\Office path\WINWORD.EXE"
for /r %%a in (*.docm) do "%winword%" /mSaveFormData "%%~fa"
popd
```

Comment: That's getting my close I think. I think the quote needed to follow the `winword=` like `winword="` instead of `"winword=` correct?

Comment: Ok. The problem I'm having now is that I get an error saying "This file could not be found." (C:\Users\...\Test.doc) where "Test Plan" is part of my file path name. I get this sort of error a few times where I have spaces in my path so it must have something to do with that. How do I deal with paths containing spaces in the set of the for statement?

Comment: That did it, the quotes around `%%~fa`, thanks! However it isn't working with the quote before `winword`, I had to put it after the `=`.